# iterative transform of standard normal random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, random-variables

Given a discrete series of random variable $n(i)$ that each element follows the standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$, another series is defined iteratively as:
$$u(i+1)=au(i)+bn(i)$$
where $0<a<1$ and $b$ any real number.

How to show that $u$ is also a normal-distributed random variable?

What is the variance of $u$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Thanks.

Comment: A linear combination of two **jointly normal** random variables is normal. Note that simply asserting that the $n(i)$ are standard normal random variables **does not** mean that the $n(i)$ are _jointly normal_.  So you need to look at the $n(i)$ some more. Did it say anywhere (maybe at the beginning of the chapter) that the $n(i)$ are _independent_ standard normal random variables?  Independent normal random variables are jointly normal random variables ....

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes you are right.  $n(i)$ are independent standard normal random variables and $u(0)=0$.  How about the variance of $u$?

Comment: So, what is $u(1)$? Can you figure out its mean and variance? If you can, write an expression for $u(2)$ and try to figure out the mean and variance of that.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks, I can get the variance of each $u(i)$.  Then how about the variance of the whole series $u$?

Comment: What is your definition of the variance of a series? As I understand it, for a _stationary_ series, the variance is a constant. For a nonstationary series, the variance is itself a series which you say you have calculated.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I get this problem when discretize an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process: $\triangle u=-\frac{1}{T}u+\sigma R$ where $R\sim N(0,1)$.  This is easily implemented using Matlab and when I increase the samples of $u(i)$, the variance of $u$ do not change significantly.  So I guess it is stationary but not sure.  I modify the question and re-post it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446243/whats-the-variance-of-this-sequence)

Comment: *Thanks, I can get the variance of each u(i)*... Then you could post this computation.